# Laravel yajra table pagination server side, cannot click the third page after click second page

Tags: php, datatables, pagination, laravel-8

So basically, this is the first page (may see the first picture), there have 8 data overall, each page will show 2 data.
[First Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhDaU.png)

So when I click the second page, the third page will be lost, cannot click. You can see the second picture ([This is the second picture at the second page, but as u can see there's no button for me to click the third page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIsgi.png))

So as you can see below I try to add Datatables and put ->setOffset($start) in the code. But its not working. Please anyone help me.

```
public function reservationListing(Request $request)
    {

        $req = $request->all();

        $query = EventReservation::selectRaw("reservation_date,event_reservations.outlet_id,event_reservations.event_id,SUM(event_reservations.total_adults) as ttl_adult,
        SUM(event_reservations.total_kids) as ttl_kid,SUM(event_reservations.total_adults + event_reservations.total_kids) as ttl_pax,
        SUM(CASE WHEN event_reservations.total_attendees is NULL then 0 Else event_reservations.total_attendees End) as ttl_attended,
        SUM(CASE WHEN payment_status = 'pending' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as ttl_pending,SUM(CASE WHEN payment_status = 'paid' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as ttl_paid,
        events.name as event_name,outlets.name as outlet_name")
            ->leftjoin("events", "events.id", "=", "event_reservations.event_id")
            ->leftjoin("outlets", "outlets.id", "=", "event_reservations.outlet_id")
            ->groupby('reservation_date')
            ->groupby('outlet_id')
            ->groupby('event_id');

        if (!empty($req['date_to']) && !empty($req['date_to'])) {
            $query->whereRaw("DATE(reservation_date) BETWEEN '".$req['date_from']."' AND '".$req['date_to']."'");
        }

        if (!empty($req['outlet_id'])) {
            $query->where("event_reservations.outlet_id", $req['outlet_id']);
        }

        if (!empty($req['event_id'])) {
            $query->where("event_reservations.event_id", $req['event_id']);
        }

        if (!empty($req['start'])) {
            $query->skip($req['start']);


        }

        if (!empty($req['start'])) {
            $query->take($req['length']);
        }
        $query->orderBy("reservation_date");
        $reservationList = $query->get();

        $start = ($request->start) ? $request->start : 0;

        return Datatables::of($reservationList)
        ->setOffset($start)
        ->addIndexColumn()  
            ->make(true);
    }
```

Comment: Show us how the server-side code calculates the correct values for `recordsTotal` (as defined [here](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Returned-data)). Apparently (according to the screenshots), this value is being mis-calculated somewhere.

Comment: @andrewJames its okay i already get the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already get the answer, I just change some of the code and delete some code which are:

```
 if (!empty($req['start'])) {
        $query->skip($req['start']);


    }

    if (!empty($req['start'])) {
        $query->take($req['length']);
    }
```

This is the full code for this function:

```
public function reservationListing(Request $request)
{

    $req = $request->all();

    $query = EventReservation::selectRaw("reservation_date,event_reservations.outlet_id,event_reservations.event_id,SUM(event_reservations.total_adults) as ttl_adult,
    SUM(event_reservations.total_kids) as ttl_kid,SUM(event_reservations.total_adults + event_reservations.total_kids) as ttl_pax,
    SUM(CASE WHEN event_reservations.total_attendees is NULL then 0 Else event_reservations.total_attendees End) as ttl_attended,
    SUM(CASE WHEN payment_status = 'pending' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as ttl_pending,SUM(CASE WHEN payment_status = 'paid' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as ttl_paid,
    events.name as event_name,outlets.name as outlet_name")
        ->leftjoin("events", "events.id", "=", "event_reservations.event_id")
        ->leftjoin("outlets", "outlets.id", "=", "event_reservations.outlet_id")
        ->groupby('reservation_date')
        ->groupby('outlet_id')
        ->groupby('event_id');

    if (!empty($req['date_to']) && !empty($req['date_to'])) {
        $query->whereRaw("DATE(reservation_date) BETWEEN '".$req['date_from']."' AND '".$req['date_to']."'");
    }

    if (!empty($req['outlet_id'])) {
        $query->where("event_reservations.outlet_id", $req['outlet_id']);
    }

    if (!empty($req['event_id'])) {
        $query->where("event_reservations.event_id", $req['event_id']);
    }

    $query->orderBy("reservation_date");

    $reservationList = $query->get();

    return Datatables::of($reservationList)
    ->make(true);
}
```